Problems using JDBC to save data into a PostgreSQL in DataBricks
Sometimes this code works, sometimes it doesn't, I have this code:
new_table_name = "table_x923"

attempts = 3
for attempt in range(attempts):
    try:
        table_data_inc.write \
            .format("jdbc") \
            .option("url", jdbc_url) \
            .option("dbtable", "schema_name.random_table_name_abc123") \
            .option("user", user_sql) \
            .option("password", password_sql) \
            .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
            .option("batchsize", 250) \
            .option("socketTimeout", "120") \
            .option("connectTimeout", "120") \
            .mode("overwrite") \
            .save()
        break
    except Exception as e:
        if attempt < attempts - 1:
            time.sleep(2 ** attempt)
            continue
        else:
            raise e


And get this error:
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o577.save.
: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:354)

Any recommendations assuring the persistance of the data resiliently? Thanks
I added the try/except, and it works sometimes and this is for an important data ingestion using pyspark to PostgreSQL.

Is there any change in the volume of data when it works vs when it fails?
Also, please check the Postgresql.conf page for the number of connections it can handle. If more applications are using at the same time, you may face this error.
